# Apache Tomcat 9 Version 9.0.76 update has caused my Java Servlet to only allow a single concurrent connection at a time

Tags: tomcat

In the past I was able to make multiple concurrent connections to my servlet using Apache Tomcat 9. Since the latest release 9.0.76 if I made multiple calls to a single servlet endpoint they will queue and not process until the previous call is completed.

I then found this in the changelog on the Apache Tomcat site:

> Fix:  66513: Add a per session Semaphore to the PersistentValve that ensures that, within a single Tomcat instance, there is no more than one concurrent request per session. Also expand the debug logging to include whether a request bypasses the Valve and the reason if a request fails to obtain the per session Semaphore. (markt)

I believe this is causing the issue.

I have tried multiple different configurations to try to resolve this issue, but in the meantime I have had to rollback to version 9.0.75, which works just fine.

An example in the server.xml I used to try an solve the problem.

```
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="175" minSpareThreads="25"/>

    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
        port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="60000" />
```

Is this something that can be fixed through a configuration change?